# Input text fields behaving strangely in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

In my application, the input text fields are behaving strangely in Chrome when I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go from one field to another. The fields are working fine when I click on them, and in any case they are working as expected in Firefox.

Comment: "strange" is a broad word. What exactly is the issue? Can you provide a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: try to set `tabindex` attribute

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the docs: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and rewrite your question.